# Get Time Gap between two date columns

Tags: sql-server, performance, time

I have this query for getting time gaps between activities, where only the activities with less than a 10 hours gap will show up.
It's running very, very slow. There are about 300 activities with less than a 10 hour gap. Any suggestions for performance?

```
WITH GapsBetweenActivities AS
(
    SELECT  ACTIVITY_ID
            ,ACTIVITY_START_TIME            
            ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ACTIVITY_START_TIME, LAG(ACTIVITY_START_TIME) OVER (ORDER BY ACTIVITY_START_TIME)) AS PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY         
    FROM    ACTIVITIES  
    WHERE   ACTIVITY_START_TIME > GETDATE() -- FUTURE ACTIVITY
)

SELECT  *
FROM    GapsBetweenActivities
WHERE   PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY IS NULL -- NULL PREVIOUS ACTIVITY (FIRST ONE IN TABLE)
        OR
        PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY > -600; -- DATE DIFF IS NEGATIVE MINUTES
```

Comment: NOTE: `DATEDIFF(HOUR...` doesn't round up... it just takes the hour portions and compares them (so the difference between 01:00:00.000 and 10:59:59.000 will still be 9, but the difference between 01:59:59.000 and 11:00:00.000 will be 10). EDIT: as for why your query is running slowly, I would guess that it's at least partially because you don't have an index on your activity_start_time?

Comment: @ZLK I tried it, and a difference of 30 minutes was shown as 1 hour, instead of half an hour (0.5). I need it to be precise in that way, and since DATEDIFF returns int... So I decided to use MINUTE instead, sorry if I sounded misleading.

Comment: Yes, using minutes instead of hours is the first step. Furthermore you might want to divide by 60.0 in order to get a decimal hour value. Last but not least, I learned that get_date() is pretty much a performance killer - did you try to declare a variable at the beginning @now datetime = getdate()? Might not be a turbo boost but at least a bit of performance tuner...